# How to Send the uploaded file to Apex using lightning:fileUpload - Salesforce lightning

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

After the Alert how do I retrieve the files that were uploaded and send them to the Apex class?

Also on the APEX class what is the input parameter type we use for receiving the file sent?

Component Code

```
<lightning:fileUpload label="Upload Multiple files" 
                               multiple="false" 
                              accept=".pdf, .png, .jpg"
                              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              aura:id="multipleUpload"
                             onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
```

JScontroller

```
({
    handleUploadFinished: function (component, event, helper) {
    // Get the list of uploaded files
    var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
        alert("Files uploaded length  : " + uploadedFiles.length);
      }    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please review the documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_fileUpload.htm

The lightning file upload component, uploads files and attaches it to a record.

You specify the record to attach the files to with the below attribute:

`recordId` => `String` => `The record Id of the record that the uploaded file is associated to.`

If you want to validate the files or have some logic to execute on them, use the below callback function provided:

`onuploadfinished` => `Action` => `The action triggered when files have finished uploading.`

The docs show this example of a callback function:

```
({
    handleUploadFinished: function (cmp, event) {
        // Get the list of uploaded files
        var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
        alert("Files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
    }
})
```

As you can see the function receives an event called `files` that can be inspected.

Comment: Hi Tiaan, thank you for the reply, I tried calling the "handleUploadFinished" callback function but in that I cannot access the file, as an example i want to know  how to calculate the size of the file I had uploaded

Comment: Hello @Raghu please use the files property passed, loop over the property (it is an array) and check the size.

Answer (score 0):

> instate of sending docId you can send file in string form using JSON.stringify(uploadedFiles[0])

```
    ({
     handleUploadFinished: function (component, event, helper) {
     var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
     var action = cmp.get("c.saveDoc");
     action.setParams({
          parentId : cmp.get("v.myRecordId"),
          contentDocId : uploadedFiles[0].documentId
      });


      action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
         var state = response.getState();
         if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "Success!",
                "message": "File "+uploadedFiles[0].name+" Uploaded successfully."
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
            var cmpEvent = cmp.getEvent("cmpEvent");
            cmpEvent.fire();
          }
          else {
            console.log("Fail");
          }

         });
         $A.enqueueAction(action);
          }
         })
```